# Infinitely many nilpotent elements in $\mathbb{C}[G]$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, finite-groups

Suppose $G$ is a finite group and $F$ is a field such that $\mathrm{char}\;F$ doesn't divide $|G|$. Suppose that $F$ is algebraically closed and $G$ is not abelian. How can I prove that $F[G]$ has infinitely many nilpotent elements?

Comment: If $x$ is nilpotent and $\lambda \in F$ then $\lambda x$ is also nilpotent. Since an algrebraically closed field is infinite, if there is one non zero nilpotent element there are infinitely many.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a fundamental result in representation theory that the group algebra of a finite group over a field with characteristic not dividing the group order is semisimple and hence, by the Artin-Wedderburn Theorem, is isomorphic to a direct product of full matrix algebras over division rings. Furthermore, if the field $F$ is algebraically closed, then these matrix algebras are over $F$ itself. If the group is nonabelian, then at least one of these matrix algebras has dimension greater than 1, and hence contains infinitely many nonzero nilpotent elements.